# How does bash `auto_resume` job control variable works?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, job-control, jobs

Chapter [7.3 Job Control Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Variables.html) in [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) has the following description about `auto_resume` variable:

> **`auto_resume`**
>
> This variable controls how the shell interacts with the user and job control. If this variable is 
>   set, single word simple commands without redirections are treated as candidates for resumption of an 
>   existing stopped job. There is no ambiguity allowed; if there is more than one job beginning with the 
>   string typed, the job most recently accessed is selected. The name of a stopped job, in this context, 
>   is the command line used to start it.
>
> If set to the value **`exact`**, the string supplied must match the 
>   name of a stopped job exactly; if set to **`substring`**, the string supplied needs to match a substring of 
>   the name of a stopped job. The `substring` value provides functionality analogous to the `%?` job 
>   identifier (see Job Control Basics).
>
> If set to **any other value**, the supplied string must be a prefix 
>   of a stopped job's name; this provides functionality analogous to the `%string` job identifier.

What is the purpose of and history behind this feature?

Are there any use cases where this functionality is really helpful?

Comment: The possible values are described in the text you're quoting from the manual; start your research by reading it ;-)

Comment: @mosvy Thanks for the edition ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any use cases where this functionality is really helpful?

<opinion>

Not really. It's only for people too lazy to type `%` or `%?`:

```
$ sleep 3600
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 3600
$ %s
sleep 3600
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 3600
$ s
bash: s: command not found
$ auto_resume=ON
$ s
sleep 3600
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 3600
```

So it allows you to resume the `sleep ...` job with just `s` instead of `%s`. Big deal.

In fact, it can be obnoxious, as typing `ss` can resume a backgrounded `ssh` instead of running the [`ss`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) command.

**Fun fact:** the `auto_resume` together with `histchars` have the distinction of being the only lowercase variables to which bash assigns a special meaning.